# Prevent form from getting empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm using asp.net with vb.net

i have one form with 2 div 1 div for login and the other one is for register and i'm using css to animate these 2 div

my problem is that when registering i need to test if the username already exists so i need to access my database and i'm using a custom validator to validate the username, so when my app goes to the vb code to validate the username the page is being reloaded and all the fields becomes empty including the error message of the validator

vb code:

```
Public Sub cusCustom_RegisterValidate(sender As Object, e As ServerValidateEventArgs)
    Dim tbuFirstName As TextBox = Page.FindControl("usernamesignup")
    If tbuFirstName.Text = form.username Then
        e.IsValid = False
        Session("validd") = False
        CustomValidator2.ErrorMessage = "username already exists"
    Else
        e.IsValid = True
        Session("validd") = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_signup_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_signup.Click
    If Session("validd") = False Then
        Response.Redirect("LOGIN.aspx#toregister")
        CustomValidator2.ErrorMessage = "Username already exists"
    End If
End Sub
```

asp code:

```
 <p> 
      <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
      <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname"  style="color: red;">*</label>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="Username is required !" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="usernamesignup" Font-Bold="true" ValidationGroup="registerGRP" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="registerGRP" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" onservervalidate="cusCustom_RegisterValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
      <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
</p>
```

when the username already exists i have to force redirection to the register div ( because when it's valid automatically the page is loaded and redirect to the login div )

so when redirecting to the register div how can i prevent the fields from getting empty and especially the validator message

any suggestion is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your code inside `if(!IsPostBack)` property of the page.

Comment: if i use `if(!IsPostBack)` the form does not get empty but does not redirect to the register div ..